# Unable to connect to MongoDB from Docker Container

Tags: docker, docker-network

I am running Mongo DB image with following command:

```
docker run -d -p 27017:27017 -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=test -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password --name=testdb mongo
```

This created container and I'm able to connect to this from robo3T.

Now I ran mongo-express image with following command and trying to above DB:

```
docker run -d -p 8081:8081 -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=test -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=testdb --name=mongo-ex mongo-express
```

But I'm getting following error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [testb:27017] on first connect [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND testb
```

If I'm creating a custom bridge network and running these two images in that container it's working.

**My question is:** As the default network is bridge network, and these containers are creating in default bridge network, why are they not able to communicate? Why is it working with custom bridge network?

Answer (score 1):

There are [two kinds of "bridge network"](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/); if you don't have a `docker run --net` option then you get the ["default" bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#use-the-default-bridge-network) which is pretty limited.  You almost always want to `docker network create` a "user-defined" bridge network, which has the standard Docker networking features.

```sh
# Use modern Docker networking
docker network create myapp
docker run -d --net myapp ... --name testdb mongo
docker run -d --net myapp ... -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=testdb mongo-express
# Because both containers are on the same --net, the first
# container's --name is usable as a host name from the second
```

The "default" bridge network that you get without `--net` by default forbids inter-container communication, and you need a special `--link` option to make the connection.  This is considered obsolete, and [the Docker documentation page describing links](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/) notes that links "may eventually be removed".

```sh
# Use obsolete Docker networking; may stop working at some point
docker run -d ... --name testdb mongo
docker run -d ... -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=testdb --link testdb mongo-express
# Containers can only connect to each other by name if they use --link
```

On modern Docker setups you really shouldn't use `--link` or the equivalent Compose `links:` option.  Prefer to use the more modern `docker network create` form.  If you're using Compose, note that [Compose creates a network named `default`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) but this is a "user-defined bridge"; in most cases you don't need any `networks:` options at all to get reasonable inter-container networking.

Comment: Thank you David Maze. ```docker run --network host -d nginx``` I'm running nginx on host network. The container started but I'm not able to access nginx on localhost:80. Can you please help here?

Comment: `--network host` disables Docker networking; you almost never need it.  This also doesn't seem directly related to the question you're asking here.

Comment: Yes David. Just related to networking. But when it disables network, I should able to access it right in that case?

I followed: https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/